# How to get access to run a D-Bus method?

Tags: linux, dbus

When I run this command to run the `org.gnome.Shell.Introspect`'s `GetWindows()` method:

```
dbus-send --session \
          --print-reply \
          --dest=org.gnome.Shell.Introspect \
          /org/gnome/Shell/Introspect \
          org.gnome.Shell.Introspect.GetWindows
```

I got this error:
`Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: GetWindows is not allowed`

How can I get access to this D-Bus interface to get the result of the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, except by patching gnome-shell (or maybe writing a shell extension to live-patch it). It's been programmed to only allow access to Introspect methods from xdg-desktop-portal-gnome/gtk. See `APP_ALLOWLIST` in `js/misc/introspect.js`.